# Mortgage term and overpayment

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I have been comparing mortgages on a banks website.

It appears that the term I choose does not affect the interest rate I am offered.

In this case the deals allow 10% overpayment per year without penalty.

In this case does it makes sense to go for a longer term so my compulsory repayments are less, then voluntarily overpay in the first 3-5 years (after which point I will most likely remortgage)? This then gives me the option to be paying less should I get into financial difficulty.

Comment: 10% of what? Of the remaining balance or of the payment amount?

Comment: A location tag would be helpful.  In the US, I'd be shocked if a 15-year mortgage didn't have a lower rate than a 30-year mortgage (not a huge difference but when rates are this low, small absolute differences are relatively large relative differences).  And I'd be surprised if you found a mortgage with prepayment penalties offered due to post-2008 regulatory changes-- it certainly wouldn't be common

Comment: that would be 10% of the outstanding balance

Comment: @JustinCave this is in the UK; i got the rates through a banks own comparision feature for its products - i don't know if the actual rates offered after application may vary based on term

Comment: @JustinCave - Rates in the UK (now that we have the location tag) tend to vary by loan-to-value (i.e. what percentage of the house's value is mortgage), but not by term. Dilitante - It's likely (based on my experience) to be 10% of the initial loan amount, rather than the outstanding balance; but I obviously won't guarantee that.

Answer (score 8):

Yes if the interest rate is the same and overpayments are applied to principal then you can get a 30-year mortgage and pay it off as if it were a 15-year mortgage.

The *risk* is that you decide that rather than overpaying you'd rather buy a car, or go on vacation, etc. and you end up paying it over 30 years anyways. A shorter term *forces* you to pay it off sooner rather than relying on personal discipline.

Comment: Just a alternative perspective, what D Stanley here calls a 'risk', I would call a 'feature'. I like that the amount required each month is lower, with a plan to overpay each month so that should an unexpected expense come up, I have the flexibility to just make that lower minimum.

As noted above, this does require discipline.

Comment: @R.Hamilton I agree, for that exact reason.